# How to write to pager subprocess in Tcl?

Tags: file-io, tcl

When trying to write to `more` subprocess in Tcl, a `broken pipe` error will occurred. It seems that `more` is exited abnormally. e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set pager [open {| more} w]

for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {
    puts $pager "$i foo"
}

close $pager
```

Can not figure out what's going wrong.

BTW, it seems OK if `less` is used instead of `more`.

---

Edit: Following Python version works properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

pager = os.popen("more", "w")

for i in range(10000):
    pager.write("{} foo".format(i))

pager.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you close the pipe, the `more` process gets a SIGPIPE signal that makes it exit, and Tcl detects that there was an exit due to a signal and produces that error.

The simplest method of dealing with it is to put a `catch` around the `close`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set pager [open {| more} w]

for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {
    puts $pager "$i foo"
}

catch {close $pager}
```

Alternatively, use `less` instead of `more`; that doesn't exit in the same way at the end of the input pipe (by default).

Comment: Tried to do this in Python and it works properly, so I think it's more a Tcl problem. (have updated the question with that Python code)